# How to place order for free

Tags: magento

I want to make some product for free in our Magento store but when user process the order then in the process of checkout, It shows error and prevent to place the order.
error is (javascript: alert)
"Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available for it".

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this is more a Magento configuration issue than a programming question. I think you are better off asking this with the Magento community

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to enable "Zero Subtotal Checkout" in the Magento Admin.

Comment: Thank you very much.....I have already resolved this issue by doing the same what you have suggested.